# correlation and p-value by using cor.test function

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

This query is giving me finite observation error, kindly help me to solve this
Currently I am trying the below code, I need to find correlation and p value between variable(genolocmean) and variable (genomean) present in genolocmerge data frame.

```
genoloccorr <- genolocmerge %>% group_by(br_field_id) %>% 
           do(tidy(cor.test(.$genolocmean,.$genomean)))
```

Comment: Is this `genolocmerge` data frame something available in R or a package?  If not, you should provided an minimum working example of your data so that users are able to replicate your work.

Comment: It is a data frame which contains columns like br_field_id , genolocmean,genomean. I want to find out the correlation between these two genolocmean,genomean

Comment: OK, your example doesn't provide enough information.  If you can't post your actual data, then you should post some similar version of it so that users can work with it in R and then hopefully provide you with a solution.  I can provide a possible answer the best I can based on the information I have at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the map functions?

`genoloccorr <- genolocmerge %>% group_by(br_field_id) %>% 
           summarise(result=map2(genolocmean,genomean,~cor.test(.x,.y)))`

This should return a data frame with a column for `br_field_id` and a list-column with the output of `cor.test()`.  If you only need the p-value and correlation, you could modify the `~cor.test(.x,.y)` by attaching an index to pull only what you need.

Without a working dataset I can't test if this code will actually work.  If it doesn't please provide a sample dataset so that I can test different ideas.